# I need to exit a methode, without returning a value

Tags: java, return, exit

I have methode that returnd the smallest value in an arrayList. However, it should return anything if the arrayList is empty. Is there something I can do?

```
private int smallest() {
 if(alList.empty()) {
  //whatever will exit the 
  //function.
 }
 small = alList.get(0);
 for(int i = 1, i < 
  alList.size(), i++) {
  if(small > alList.get(i)){
   small = alList.get(i)
  }
 }
 return small;
}

//Thanks for your help.
```

Comment: Just throw an exception. It's not what you asked for, but the right thing to do. Its up to the caller to provide a list the method can work with.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to return an `int`, then no, you must return a value.

If you can change the method signature, you can:

1. Return an `Integer` and so return `null`.
2. Return `Optional<Integer>` and return an empty Optional.

Comment: kudos for the Optional. Never heard of that before :)

Comment: Just to add that there's also `OptionalInt` which (although less of a general answer) is directly there for cases such as this.  Additionally sentinel Objects can be used for this functionality if there is some limiting factor on the output - for example, if it should always be non-negative, returning `-1` (or anything similar) is often used to indicate a failed operation.

Comment: So you are sayong that if I use Interger instead of int, I can return a NULL value?  Like this? private Integer Smallest() { return Integer.NULL}

Comment: yes, but like this: `private Integer Smallest() { return null; }`

Answer (score 0):

There are many options. The three most obvious ones:

1. throw an exception: `if (alList.isEmpty()) throw new IllegalStateException("alList must not be empty when invoking smallest()");
2. decide on a sentinel value, for example `0`, and return that. Update the docs to make it clear that 0 is returned for empty lists.
3. `private int smallest(int valueIfEmpty) { if (alList.isEmpty()) return valueIfEmpty; ... }` - i.e. pass the value to be returned in that case, so that the caller can decide what should happen.